# Update ProgressBar in another window from a function?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, progress-bar

I have a Background Task that uploads a file, and i want it to report the progress to a progressbar on another form.  How would i go about that? I'm slightly new to C# but long time VB .net programmer.

I was messing with this code but its totally wrong.

```
System.Windows.Forms.Form progForm = new ProgressWindows();
Control[] ctrls = progForm.Controls.Find("fileProgress1", true);
```

Comment: Winform app? Do you want to show the exact percentage? Do you have any way to know the percentage? Would you like to use BacgroundWorker? Sorry for many questions :-)

Comment: I do, actually.  Its a MS VSTO Outlook plugin.  But during progress of transferring, i use percentageComplete = (int)(totalReadCount / (double)fileSize * 100); and i get a simple 1 to 100 progress. I have tested this by messagebox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you problem is just accessing the fileProgress1. The easiest solution is make it public in the ProgressWindow class. By default controls are private.

[image]

Then you can access the fileProgress1 control as below.

```
ProgressWindows progForm = new ProgressWindows();
//progForm.fileProgress1
```

However the better way is exposing a public method in the PrefressWindows class that updates the progress.

In the ProgressWindows Class

```
public void UpdateProgressBar(int percentage)
{
    // Set the progress in the progress bar.
    fileProgress1.Percentage = percentage;
}
```

Call the above method as below.

```
ProgressWindows progForm = new ProgressWindows();
progForm.UpdateProgressBar(percentage);
```

Comment: @Dan C: What did you do? first way or the second way? Both should work. But the second one is the preferred way.

Comment: I see why calling the method as you put it would be better, however i'm getting this in the Task:


Error 1 'System.Windows.Forms.Form' does not contain a definition for 'UpdateProgressBar' and no extension method 'UpdateProgressBar' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Forms.Form' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Second way, see the last post :)

Comment: ProgressWindows class in a different library? Did you compile it once update the code?

Comment: No, its in the same lib, and Intellisense picks up when i start typing ProgressW.... Yes i tried compiling, no go.

Comment: Post your whole code. You seems to be doing wrong something else.

Comment: I dont have much room to post, but this is the window code:

namespace SpartaMessage_OutlookAddin_2010
{
    public partial class ProgressWindow : Form
    {
        
        public ProgressWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void ProgressWindow_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
        public void UpdateProgressBar(int percentage)
        {
            // Set the progress in the progress bar.
            fileProgress1.Value = percentage;
        }
    }

}

Comment: And yes, i took the "s" off the ProgressWindows, since that was a typo. Im not going to be able to post the whole caller code but this is the important part:

percentageComplete = (int)(totalReadCount / (double)fileSize * 100);
                            System.Windows.Forms.Form progForm = new ProgressWindow();
                            progForm.UpdateProgressBar(percentageComplete);

Comment: Declare the progForm as below. This should work. ProgressWindow progForm = new ProgressWindow();

Comment: Also I'm not sure if you saw from my other posts, but this is a VSTO outlook plugin.  I'm calling the form method from inside a Task being called to action within the main .cs file of the project.

Comment: Below should fix your problem.

ProgressWindow progForm = new ProgressWindow();

progForm.UpdateProgressBar(percentageComplete);

Comment: That did it, but 2 things.. 

1) when the progresswindow loads, the progresswindow hourglasses until complete.

2) if i close the window and re-open it, the progress is nothing.  I assume thats because we are calling new ProgressWindow();, any way we can update the control if the window is shown or not?

Comment: 1. May be because the main thread is busy and don't get a chance to update the progress bar? I have never used Threading.Tasks. What I know is Backgroundworker works fine in similar cases.  2. Make sure you use the same instance of progressBar if you have created one earlier. I am not sure what you do there with the ProgressWindow.

Comment: Nah, the main thread i can still navigate around, its the ProgressWindow that once i click away from i can never get back to once its complete.  As for #2, i'm not changing the instance of the progreassBar, its just a simple form with the control dropped onto it.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using a [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) then just call [ReportProgress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/12by6848.aspx). Otherwise you'll need to dispatch the UI change to the correct thread. In WinForms see the [Control.InvokeRequired](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.invokerequired.aspx) property and related methods. The WPF equivalent is [DispatcherObject.VerifyAccess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcherobject.verifyaccess.aspx).

Edit: Visual Studio isn't in front of me so there may be some minor compile errors.

```
public partial class MyForm : Form
{
    public MyForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent(); // fileProgress1 setup. 
    }

    private void StartTask()
    {
        Task t1 = new Task(BackgroundMethod1, fileProgress1); // Explicitly pass a reference to the progress bar.
        Task t2 = new Task(BackgroundMethod2); // Use a method that has access to the bar.
        Task t5 = new Task(BackgroundMethod3, IncrementPBMethod); // Pass an action to the background method. Abstracting the physical progress bar as something where you can set the progress.
        Task t4 = new Task(delegate() { /* fileProgress1 referened*/ }); // Create a closure. I don't recommend this method.
    }

    private static void BackgroundMethod1(ProgressBar pb)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
        {
            if(pb.InvokeRequired)
            {
                pb.Invoke(delegate() { pb.Value = i; });
            }

            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
    }

    private void BackgroundMethod2()
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
        {
            if(fileProgress1.InvokeRequired)
            {
                fileProgress1.Invoke(delegate() { fileProgress1.Value = i; });
            }

            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
    }

    private static BackgroundMethod3(Action<int> setProgress)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
        {
            setProgress(i);
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
    }

    private void IncrementPBMethod(int value)
    {
        if(fileProgress1.InvokeRequired)
        {
            fileProgress1.Invoke(IncrementPBMethod, value);
        }
        else
        {
            fileProgress1.Value = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm using System.Threading.Tasks.  Either way, i just want to set the value from inside the task. The problem is, i cant access the control inside of the form.  In VB this would be something like Dim progbar1 as ProgressBar = CType(ProgressWindows.FindControl("fileProgress1), ProgressBar).

Comment: Rather than try to use `FindControl` pass the progress bar control to the `Task`'s constructor or pass a method that has access.

Comment: Give me a moment to write something up.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that your second form (the one you want to show progress in) is instantiated in the form doing the "task". Why don't you simply create a public method in the second form that excepts an integer parameter to update the progress bar value? Seems like a relatively easy solution.

Comment: That would be because the form won't be instantiated from the form doing the task.  This is a Outlook plugin. There will be an if statement seeing if the window is open before reporting the progress.